# How to display terminaltables (with box drawing characters) in tkinter widgets (Python3)?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, tkinter, symbols

I have some code that came from an old terminal app using `terminaltables`, a module that allows to create terminal compatible tables using box drawing symbols (works ok in UTF-8 configured terminals). I don't want to rewrite it, but would like to reuse it right now, as is, in a Python 3 tkinter application that should display those tables in a `ttk.Label` or inside a text widget.

I know that it is possible to force `terminaltables` to display only ASCII symbols, but I word rather prefer box drawing symbols, which give cleaner lines. Is it possible?

Comment: You're just wanting to create a table based on a list of lists? Or are you just wanting to take the output of terminaltables as-is and display it in a text widget?

Comment: Yes. I have previous code that does that and uses terminaltables. I am trying to "print" them in a tkinter widget while I don't remake the code. I have those strings stored in a SQL items database...

Comment: But the encoding seems to be incorrect for the box drawing characters. I plan to remake that part of the application someday, but right now I am also trying to understand if it is possible to do it this way.